# Comparing a string and a char c#

Tags: c#, string, char, operands

I am working on a console Hangman game in c#. I am trying to compare user inputted letter against the letters in the random word I have generated. Error i get is "Operator "==" cannot be applied to operands of type "string" and "char". What other ways could I go about doing this? Ive googled a lot but I haven't found any ideas.

```
public static void LetterChecker(string word)
    {
        int userGuesses = 6;
        string userInputGuess;

        while(userGuesses > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please guess a letter");
            userInputGuess = Console.ReadLine();
            foreach(var letter in word)
            {
                if(userInputGuess == letter)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("this letter is in word, guess again");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Incorrect guess");
                    userGuesses--;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can use `Console.ReadKey().KeyChar` instead of `Console.ReadLine()` since you want only a single character from the user.

Comment: `if(userInputGuess[0] == letter)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of using `Console.ReadLine` which reads an entire line, use `Console.ReadKey`:

> Obtains the next character or function key pressed by the user.
>   The pressed key is displayed in the console window.

```
char userInputGuess;
...
Console.WriteLine("Please guess a letter");
userInputGuess = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
```

Answer (score 0):

The return type of `Console.ReadLine()` is a string. By this your `userInputGuess` is of type string, and this is why you receive the error. With slight modification your code can work. Instead of:

```
if(userInputGuess == letter)
```

use:

```
if(userInputGuess[0] == letter)
```

This will read the first letter of your line. But as you may guess, this is not the best solution in this case.

The better approach would be to read only one letter from the console. Like this:

```
var userInputGuess = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar; (and get rid of the previous declaration)
```

The result of this is of type char, and you won't have a problem in the comparison.

Comment: Two things here: `userInputGuess[0]` would throw an IndexOutOfRangeException if the user just pressed enter (generating an empty string); and `userInputGuess` would have to be declared as `char` for the second approach to work

Comment: Agreed. I missed that for the char declaration.